# Method to Delete members in Addons

Tags: members, delete

Is there a library, class or method that an addon can access to be able to delete members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, just load the Member model:

```
ee()->load->model('member_model');
ee()->member_model->delete_member($member_id, $heir_id);
```

`$member_id` can be a single member, or an array of ids.

`$heir_id` is the `member_id` that should take authorship of any existing entries belonging to the member being deleted.

Comment: Does this delete_member return some value that can be used as a flag to check if delete is succesful or not? In any case, it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Nope, it does not return anything unfortunately. Have you stripped your code down to just the member deletion as a test?

Comment: Okay your solution turned out to be correct. There was a hook that triggers on member_delete hook that was not returning the $member_ids needed for the delete to work.